# Mysql error when after fresh install unable to login

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql 8 version in my mac.
when i do this i am getting below error.

```
➜  ~ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I tried this also.

```
➜  mysql cd 
➜  ~ mysql_secure_installation                                              

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Here showing something like this.

```
➜  ~ ps aux | grep mysql
root             18066   0.0  0.1  4413016   5608 s001  TN   11:45AM   0:00.04 sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
soubhagyapradhan 26834   0.0  0.0  4268424    696 s001  S+    4:12PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr 
--exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=
.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql
```

Please help how to fix this ?

Comment: Try `sudo mysql`. With a default install you do not need a password when connecting as root and connecting locally. (at least on  a mac)

Comment: Password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)